# JavaScript map Function replacing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the quantity value of a certain object in my cart array.
Each object in cart array have (id, item_id, quantity, name, price).

But when my map function find that specific cart, instead of changing only quantity of that object, it replaces the whole object with the quantity value.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**action.payload**

```
{
    id: "a6e1868f-e1bc-4180-abc6-328fdd8e922f",
    quantity: 7
}
```

```
state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? cartItem.quantity = action.payload.quantity : cartItem)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id ?
> cartItem.quantity = action.payload.quantity : cartItem)

when you return some element say `x` at some index from callback of `map`, the corresponding element which *was being mapped* is replaced with this `x`, that is how map works.

You are returning this:

```
cartItem.quantity = action.payload.quantity // btw don't mutate state items like this
```

```js
let x;
console.log(x=9); // logs 9

console.log([1,2].map(y=>y=9)) // logs [9,9]
```

You want immutable approach since you are iterating state items:

```js
let newVal=99;

let res = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}].map(cartItem => 
    cartItem.a === 1 ? {
        ...cartItem,
        quantity: newVal
    } : cartItem
);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator to copy all the properties of `item` object, and then, you can replace quantity with `action.payload.quantity`

```js
let cartItem = {
  id: "a6e1868f-e1bc-4180-abc6-328fdd8e922f",
  quantity: 5
}

let action = {
  payload: {
    id: "a6e1868f-e1bc-4180-abc6-328fdd8e922f",
    quantity: 7
  }
}

let cart = [cartItem]

let result = cart.map(item=>{
  if(item.id === action.payload.id){
    return {...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity};
  } else{
    return item;
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @g-moniava Yeah, I forgot about that. Updated the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Lets look at how Map function works:**

Map function gets an Array .. goes through it while using function you define to map every element of 1st array to 2nd (new array).

You return just a number if id's are same so new element of new array will be just number:

`|are id's same| ? YEP return number : NOPE return <object>`

It should be:

`|are id's same| ? YEP return <object> : NOPE return <object>`

**Fix of original code:**

```js
state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, quantity: action.payload.quantity} : cartItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are using arrow functions "without a body" (in other words, without using `{}`). This means that your arrow function is implicitly returning the resulting value of any expression succeeding the `=>` symbol. In this case it will be `action.payload.quantity` or `cartItem` depending if the item ID is matched or not.

Additionally, I assume that you are using the result of the `map` operation (a new array with the returned items) to update your state.

If you are using Redux Toolkit or something else to ensure immutability (I assume you do because your code however is not respecting immutability as inner items are being returned as references and not as new values), you could replace your `map` function with a `for` loop or other loop structure (like `Array.prototype.find`) that allows you to interrupt the loop after finding the item you was looking for.

If you want to fix your code and leave it as it is (not recommended), you can do as follows:

```js
state.cart.map(cartItem => {
  if (cartItem.id === action.payload.id) {
    cartItem.quantity = action.payload.quantity;
  }

  return cartItem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in

```
previous:  state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? cartItem.quantity = action.payload.quantity : cartItem)

you can check this:

correct:   state.cart.map(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? {...cartItem,quantity:action.payload.quantity} : cartItem)
```